# How to use the mysql sum() function to calculate the sum of each row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use mysql to traverse all the `goods_id` in the `goods` table, and then query the sum of each row in the `order_goods` table based on all `goods_id`.Can you solve this problem?

**1.Create goods table and insert table**

```
CREATE TABLE `goods` (
`goods_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`goods_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`goods_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `goods` (`goods_id`, `goods_name`) VALUES
(1, 'Apple'),
(2, 'Xiaomi'),
(3, 'Huawei');
```

**2.Create order_goods and insert table**

```
CREATE TABLE `order_goods` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`goods_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`goods_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`goods_num` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `order_goods` (`id`, `order_id`, `goods_id`, `goods_name`, 
`goods_num`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 'iPhone X', 2),
(2, 2, 1, 'iPhone 8 plus', 1),
(3, 3, 2, 'Y69A', 1),
(4, 4, 2, 'X21', 3),
(5, 5, 3, 'nova 3', 1),
(6, 6, 3, 'P20 Pro', 3),
(7, 7, 3, 'Mate 10 Pro', 5);
```

**3.Query the goods table**

```
mysql> select * from goods;
+----------+------------+
| goods_id | goods_name |
+----------+------------+
|        1 | Apple      |
|        2 | Xiaomi     |
|        3 | Huawei     |
+----------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**4.Query the order_goods table**

```
mysql> select * from order_goods;
+----+----------+----------+---------------+-----------+
| id | order_id | goods_id | goods_name    | goods_num |
+----+----------+----------+---------------+-----------+
|  1 |        1 |        1 | iPhone X      |         2 |
|  2 |        2 |        1 | iPhone 8 plus |         1 |
|  3 |        3 |        2 | Y69A          |         1 |
|  4 |        4 |        2 | X21           |         3 |
|  5 |        5 |        3 | nova 3        |         1 |
|  6 |        6 |        3 | P20 Pro       |         3 |
|  7 |        7 |        3 | Mate 10 Pro   |         5 |
+----+----------+----------+---------------+-----------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**5.I want to try to get this effect！**

```
+----+----------+----------+---------------+
| id | goods_id | goods_name    | num      |
+----+----------+----------+---------------+
|  1 |        1 | Apple         |   3      |
|  2 |        2 | Xiaomi        |   4      |
|  3 |        3 | Huawei        |   9      |
+----+----------+----------+---------------+
```

For example, write `sum(g.goods_num) as num`

**How to write the sql statement above?**

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/52387057/2469308

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Firstly, do a [INNER JOIN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx) between the two tables, using `goods_id`.
- Then, do a [grouping](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx) of `goods_id` using `GROUP BY` clause.
- Eventually, using aggregation function [SUM](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sum/) function, get the desired sum value and [Alias](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/) it as `num`.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT g.goods_id, 
       g.goods_name, 
       SUM(og.goods_num) AS num 
FROM goods g 
JOIN order_goods og ON og.goods_id = g.goods_id 
GROUP BY g.goods_id, g.goods_name
```

Answer (score 2):

`X` is the query which u do group by to have `SUM()`
Then u join it with `goods` to have the name and id and whatever u need from this table
This might be better with performance to do the group by first

```
    WITH X AS
   (
    SELECT goods_id,SUM(goods_num) AS num
    FROM order_goods
    GROUP BY goods_id
    )

    SELECT G.goods_name , X.num 
    FROM X
    INNER JOIN goods G  ON G.goods_id = X.goods_id
```

No `WITH` clause so bring your join to your query
like this:

```
SELECT goods_id,SUM(goods_num) AS num
   FROM order_goods OG
   INNER JOIN goods G  ON G.goods_id = OG.goods_id
   GROUP BY OG.goods_id    -- or G.goods_name
```

Comment: Side note: This is a MySQL 8.0+ only query.

Comment: @RaymondNijland If you mean no WITH clause, then use a join directly. I wish it help

Comment: "I wish it help" well iam not the topicstarter

Answer (score 1):

Use inner join and aggregation with group by:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae4fd9/3

```
   select go.goods_id,g.goods_name,sum(goods_num) as num
from goods g inner join order_goods go
on g.goods_id=go.goods_id
group by g.goods_name,go.goods_id
```

Output:

```
goods_id    goods_name  num
1           Apple        3
3           Huawei       9
2           Xiaomi       4
```